# Hashing the added value in the database before adding it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I must hash database values before add to db and rehash after select for human friendly readable. Now I create `"Helper\Helpers.php"` in `app` folder. In the helpers file I have functions for encrypt/decrypt values. Helper file registered to composer autoloads:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":[
        "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

In my opinion this method (file registration in the composer) is an unprotected option for registering a file of a function stored in itself for encryption. For more reliable protection where can I store and use files with encryption and decryption functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model defined, I would suggest [Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators). It would allow you to encrypt the value before written to storage and then decrypt when read out:

```
// mutator
public function setMyHashedValueAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['my_hashed_value'] = encrypt($value);
}

// accessor
public function getMyHashedValueAttribute($value)
{
    return decrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: When I register to laravel project my personal info is encrypted. When I want login with my email from database Laravel can't found my email and return error: `These credentials do not match our records.`. It can't decrypt email on login. Where I can decrypt login info and get access to app? @DigitalDrifter

Comment: You will probably need to compare against the hashed value using `Hash::check`, like `Hash::check('foo@example.com', $hashedEmail)`. Alternatively, you can hash the email address when the request is posted to the server so Laravel will use the hashed value when it does the lookup in the db.